# Deploying Django with Rpy2 to Heroku

Tags: python, django, r, heroku

I am a novice hitting the limits of my ability to get something small with django and rpy2 working on Heroku.  In particular, I am trying to test the concurrency vulnerability rpy2 creates, to see if Heroku protects against it (via dyno isolation?).

Deploying the django sample is fine, but adding rpy2 hits an unsatisified R dependency

```
git push heroku master
Counting objects: 11, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (9/9), done.
Writing objects: 100% (11/11), 3.97 KiB, done.
Total 11 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Python app detected
-----> No runtime.txt provided; assuming python-2.7.3.
-----> Preparing Python runtime (python-2.7.3)
-----> Installing Distribute (0.6.34)
-----> Installing Pip (1.2.1)
-----> Installing dependencies using Pip (1.2.1)
       Downloading/unpacking Django==1.5 (from -r requirements.txt (line 1))
         Running setup.py egg_info for package Django

       Downloading/unpacking argparse==1.2.1 (from -r requirements.txt (line 2))
         Running setup.py egg_info for package argparse

           no previously-included directories found matching 'doc/_build'
           no previously-included directories found matching 'env24'
           no previously-included directories found matching 'env25'
           no previously-included directories found matching 'env26'
           no previously-included directories found matching 'env27'
       Downloading/unpacking rpy2==2.3.4 (from -r requirements.txt (line 3))
         Running setup.py egg_info for package rpy2

           sh: R: not found
           Error: Tried to guess R's HOME but no R command in the PATH.
           Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
           running egg_info

       creating pip-egg-info/rpy2.egg-info

       writing pip-egg-info/rpy2.egg-info/PKG-INFO

       writing top-level names to pip-egg-info/rpy2.egg-info/top_level.txt

       writing dependency_links to pip-egg-info/rpy2.egg-info/dependency_links.txt

       writing manifest file 'pip-egg-info/rpy2.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'

       warning: manifest_maker: standard file '-c' not found



       sh: R: not found

       Error: Tried to guess R's HOME but no R command in the PATH.

       ----------------------------------------
       Command python setup.py egg_info failed with error code 1 in /app/build/rpy2
       Storing complete log in /app/.pip/pip.log
 !     Heroku push rejected, failed to compile Python app

To git@heroku.com:infinite-plateau-7086.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:infinite-plateau-7086.git'
```

adding init.r causes Heroku recognition of an R app and gets R up

```
    $ git push heroku master
Counting objects: 13, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (11/11), done.
Writing objects: 100% (13/13), 4.15 KiB, done.
Total 13 (delta 1), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Fetching custom git buildpack... done
-----> R app detected
       Vendoring R 2.15.1
       Downloading and unpacking R binaries
       Executing init.r script
       R 2.15.1 successfully installed
-----> Discovering process types

-----> Compiled slug size: 96.7MB
-----> Launching... done, v5
       http://infinite-plateau-7086.herokuapp.com deployed to Heroku

To git@heroku.com:infinite-plateau-7086.git
 * [new branch]      master -> master
```

but with or without the init.r file, app recognition does not see django with R up

```
$ git push heroku master
Counting objects: 5, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 289 bytes, done.
Total 3 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Fetching custom git buildpack... done
 !     Heroku push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected

To git@heroku.com:infinite-plateau-7086.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:infinite-plateau-7086.git'
```

I am using the [r buildpack](https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi) and [multi buildpack](https://github.com/ddollar/heroku-buildpack-multi) to allow for the r django interaction.  Anyone have an idea how to resolve the above dependency conflict (because I want to use the two together eventually), or whether R and python interaction cannot scale safely on Heroku?

Comment: I fixed some of the problem by correctly configuring the multipack to look for the python buildpack and R buildpack in .buildpacks.  Still need to configure where rpy looks for R on Heroku, though.

Comment: rpy2 is looking for an executable R somewhere in the $PATH.

Comment: The solution ended up being forking the Python buildpack to add to the $PATH, because buildpack installs are transactional and not stateful.